# How to decrease execution time in a SQL scalar function with hardcoded parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an existing scalar function that works extremely well for me. Execution of a basic query using this function completes in less than 1 second. Below is the current format of the function.

```
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @TEM VARCHAR(250);  
    SET @TEM = '';  

    SELECT  
        TOP 1 @TEM = ISNULL(B1_CHECKLIST_COMMENT,'')     
    FROM  
        BCHCKBOX  
    WHERE  
        B1_PER_ID1 = @PID1 AND  
        B1_PER_ID2 = @PID2 AND  
        B1_PER_ID3 = @PID3 AND  
        REC_STATUS = 'A' AND  
        SERV_PROV_CODE = 'Code' AND  
        BCHCKBOX.B1_CHECKBOX_GROUP = 'APPLICATION' AND  
        UPPER(B1_CHECKBOX_DESC) LIKE UPPER(@info_label) ;  

    RETURN(@TEM);  
END
```

The parameters @PID1,2,3 are always the same value in my queries and never change. So whenever I use the function in a query it is always formatted as follows.

```
MyFunction(ID1,ID2,ID3,’Label’)
```

Since the value for the first three parameters are always ID1,2,3 I would like to hardcode them into the function to where I just need to type the following for the function.

```
MyFunction(‘Label’)
```

The way I attempted to do this was by changing the function to the following.

```
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @TEM VARCHAR(250);  
    SET @TEM = '';  

    SELECT  
        TOP 1 @TEM = ISNULL(B1_CHECKLIST_COMMENT,'')      
    FROM  
        BCHCKBOX X  
    WHERE  
        X.B1_PER_ID1 = ID1 AND  
        X.B1_PER_ID2 = ID2 AND  
        X.B1_PER_ID3 = ID3 AND  
        X.REC_STATUS = 'A' AND  
        X.SERV_PROV_CODE = 'Code' AND  
        X.B1_CHECKBOX_GROUP = 'APPLICATION' AND  
        UPPER(B1_CHECKBOX_DESC) LIKE UPPER(@info_label) ;  

    RETURN(@TEM);  
END
```

In the revised function I aliased the table and then just used the actual values (ID1,2,3) instead of the parameters. The function works just as it did before. But, the execution time has increase to approximately 2 minutes for the exact same query that was taking less than 1 second.

Why would hardcoding the values drastically increase the execution time? Is there a better way to format this function to realize the same execution times as noticed in the original function?

### Thanks in advance!

Original post edited below to illustrate the function after edits completed based on those recommended by @AXIMIM and @SeanLange

```
ALTER  FUNCTION  [dbo].[FN_GetASIValue](@info_label  VARCHAR(250)) RETURNS VARCHAR (500)  AS    
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE
            @TEM VARCHAR(250),
            @ID1 VARCHAR(20),
            @ID2 VARCHAR(20),
            @ID3 VARCHAR(20);

        SELECT
            @TEM = '',
            @ID1 = 'B1_PER_ID1',
            @ID2 = 'B1_PER_ID2',
            @ID3 = 'B1_PER_ID3'

        SELECT
            TOP 1 @TEM = ISNULL(B1_CHECKLIST_COMMENT,'')

        FROM
            BCHCKBOX
        WHERE
            B1_PER_ID1 = @ID1 AND
            B1_PER_ID2 = @ID2 AND
            B1_PER_ID3 = @ID3 AND
            REC_STATUS = 'A' AND
            SERV_PROV_CODE = 'Code' AND
            B1_CHECKBOX_GROUP = 'APPLICATION'
        ORDER BY  B1_CHECKBOX_IND;
        RETURN(@TEM);
    END
```

The execution of this function using the following call completes in less than a second with the same number of rows returned as the original function.

```
FN_GetASIValue('location')
```

But, the value for the location column in the results are blank. The original function did return text in the location column.

Comment: Is ID1 (for example) the literal value? It should probably have single quotes around it if so: `X.B1_PER_ID1 = 'ID1' AND`

Comment: ID1 is a literal value. When I originally revised the query I did use 'ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'. In my head that made sense as it is text. But, the query returned no records. It is only when I do not use the quotes that the query works.

Comment: Does the query that returned in a second produce the same number of rows as the query that takes 2 minutes?

Comment: You might try `X.B1_PER_ID1 = N'ID1' AND` to make sure your string literal is being treated as `NVARCHAR`, just in case.  I have had that break things in the past.

Comment: I'm not understanding how `ID1`, `ID2`, and `ID3` can be valid literals.  Are there fields in `BCHCKBOX` with that name?  Because that's what the query parser should think that they are: field names.  What data type were `@PID1`, `@PID2`, and `@PID3`?

Comment: @BaconBits, that is indeed what I am wondering.  This code, as is, should not parse.

Comment: @KeithAlvis, just a shot in the dark, but does the `BCHCKBOX` table have columns named `ID1`, `ID2`, `ID3`?  That's the only way I can imagine this parsing, and it could also explain why you get 0 rows back...

Comment: There are some glaring issues with this function too. You are using top 1 but no order by. You are using LIKE that is behaving like an =. You have functions in the last predicate to evaluate UPPER which is pointless unless the collation is case sensitive.

Comment: Is the actual value for `ID1` in your query the string `"ID1"`?  Or is `ID1` just a substitute you're using within this question for the actual literal value?

Comment: ID1,2,3 was just a substitute for the actual literal value. That was my attempt to "simplify" the code for easier communication of the issue. But, it had the opposite effect.  Sorry for the confustion

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question, so here what you should take a look at.

There is two causes possible for the new version to be slow.

1) Hardcoded value aren't the same type as in the table BCHCKBOX and SQL perform an implicit conversion on all record. This conversion prevent index from being used properly and is also extra overhead.

2) The query doesn't use the previous Execution Plan anymore since there is no more parameter. A new execution plan need to be created.

As a suggestion to "FIX" the issue, you could simply declare the hardcoded value as variable in the function body. This way, you avoid the issues and still get the benefit to have only one parameter function.

Here is what I mean.  (Assuming the type is VARCHAR(50). Please use the same type as they were in parameter)

```
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @TEM VARCHAR(250),
            @ID1 VARCHAR(50),  
            @ID2 VARCHAR(50),  
            @ID3 VARCHAR(50)  

    SELECT  @TEM = '',
            @ID1 = 'ID1',
            @ID2 = 'ID2',
            @ID3 = 'ID3'

    SELECT  
        TOP 1 @TEM = ISNULL(B1_CHECKLIST_COMMENT,'')      
    FROM  
        BCHCKBOX X  
    WHERE  
        X.B1_PER_ID1 = @ID1 AND  
        X.B1_PER_ID2 = @ID2 AND  
        X.B1_PER_ID3 = @ID3 AND  
        X.REC_STATUS = 'A' AND  
        X.SERV_PROV_CODE = 'Code' AND  
        X.B1_CHECKBOX_GROUP = 'APPLICATION' AND  
        UPPER(B1_CHECKBOX_DESC) LIKE UPPER(@info_label) ;  

    RETURN(@TEM);  
END
```

Also, you should take a look at Sean Lange's comment. He point out some others issues within the function that should be taken into account.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the suggestions. I made the edits per the suggestions made by Sean Lange. With the edits I then declared the hardcoded values inside the function. Unfortunately this resulted in blank values when the query was executed. I will see if there is a way I can comment with the edited code for review.

Comment: Try to do one modification at the time. This way, we will know if the function is broken because of adjustment made the tackle issues raised by Sean or by the usage of declared variable within the function.